# Google appscript function to automatically populate date in a cell based on when I change value of another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to track the receipt date of when a decision was made in column W of my spreadsheet. I would like it to automatically update when I change the dropdown value in the Award Status Column (Column H) to "Won".

I tried writing an appscript function that would do this based on an onEdit trigger but it keeps failing. This is what I've put together:

[Appscript Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8YaN.png)

Comment: Can you provide your current script as a text instead of an image? Also, can you provide the details of `but it keeps failing`?

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your description:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //for all sheets
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.value == "Won") {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,23).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

for a particular sheet

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.value == "Won") {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,23).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```